# How JavaScript malware targets browsers?

Tags: malware, web-browser

What are the main components that JavaScript malware targets on the browsers ? Which aspects of browsers on which JavaScript takes advantage to exploit them ? And which techniques are used by malicious web content to attack browsers ?

Comment: @Xander thank you for the link, but the question there is how to mitigate the attack, nothing to do with my question.

Comment: @Xander I am asking about JS malware and browsers.

Comment: Parrado - the linked question covers JS malware and browsers.